# Consultation about date format in java for android

Tags: java, android

i have this date:  `Date d = new Date(2012, 8, 1)`;

but in the screen i see: `61304700000000`

how to fix it that i can see: `01/08/2012`

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat dmy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dmy.format(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
Date dNow = new Date( );
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("d/m/y");
System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));
```

Or use `printf`:

```
System.out.printf("%n/%d/%y", dNow);
```

Answer (score 0):

`61304700000000` what you get on screen is the 64 bit long value starting from Jan 1, 1970.

If you do this...

```
Date d = new Date(61304700000000L);
System.out.println(d);
```

**Output:**

```
Mon Sep 02 08:50:00 IST 3912
```

**Do this to get** `day/Month/Year` (eg: 00/00/0000)

`System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY").format(new Date()));`